# Sort xml by value with XmlTextReader C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

Im new to C# and Im currently working with XML-files. I have sumbled across the XmlTextReader object. I want to sort some attributes In my XML-file by value, but I can't find any easy way to do this with XmlTextReader?

XDocument have the OrderBy-property, but does XmlTextReader have any similar?

XML to sort

```
<Order>
  <orderdate>1998-04-22T00:00:00</orderdate>
</Order>
<Order>
  <orderdate>1998-04-07T00:00:00</orderdate>
</Order>
<Order>
  <orderdate>1998-04-30T00:00:00</orderdate>
</Order>
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `XmlTextReader` *Represents a reader that provides fast, non-cached, **forward-only** access to XML data.*  So basically no, it doesn't do sorting, and `XDocument` is probably your best bet; if you explain your problem in more detail we might be able to give an alternative suggestion.  By the way, this class is obsolete, use [`XmlReader.Create()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.create%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I have an xml-file with different different <OrderDate> attributes containing dates. I want to sort this attributes based on their values In ascending order.

Comment: Why do you want to use the xmltextreader indestead of xdocument?

Comment: xmltextreader seems to be easy to understand compared to xdocument? But I will give the xdocument a shot.

Comment: To be able to sort, you have to read the entire parent of the items you want to sort.  Then use this :  parent.Descendants("abc").OrderBy(x => x);

Comment: Can you update your question to include an example of the XML you want to sort?

Comment: @dbc: Check my updated question.

Comment: @Bryan - that's not valid XML, there's no single [root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element).

Comment: @dbc: I have just pasted the attributes that I want to sort.

Comment: @Bryan - In order to sort the elements most easily one needs to know their [namespace](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp), which may be specified by a default namespace of a parent element.

Comment: There are no *attributes* in sample you've posted - only elements with text values. Also not that in XML order of attributes for an element does not matter - so you question is probably about something else OR you are using term "attribute" in some meaning not related to XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `XmlTextReader` *Represents a reader that provides fast, non-cached, **forward-only** access to XML data.*  Thus it isn't really sufficient for sorting XML data, as sorting requires comparing and rearranging elements that are currently out of order.  Instead, the `XDocument` class would be your best bet.

Since you only give a fragment of your XML, it's unclear whether your elements `Order` and `orderdate` belong in the [default namespace](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) of some parent element.  If they do not belong in any namespace, you can use [`XDocument.Descendants(XName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.descendants%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) as follows, taking advantage of the [implicit conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.op_implicit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of string to [`XName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
        var items = xdocument.Descendants("Order")
            .OrderBy(o => (DateTime?)o.Element("orderdate"))
            .ToList();
```

If the elements belong in a namespace specified on the root XML element, you need specify that namespace in your query using [`XNamespace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace(v=vs.110).aspx), from which you can construct a full `XName` for `Order` to use in your `Descendants` query:

```
        XNamespace ns = xdocument.Root.Name.Namespace;

        var items = xdocument.Descendants(ns + "Order")
            .OrderBy(o => (DateTime?)o.Element(ns + "orderdate"))
            .ToList();
```

Or if the namespace is specified by some intermediate element rather than the root element, it may be easiest to specify the namespace as a string literal:

```
        XNamespace ns = "http://MiddleNamespace";

        var items = xdocument.Descendants(ns + "Order")
            .OrderBy(o => (DateTime?)o.Element(ns + "orderdate"))
            .ToList();
```

Working [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pmW9LG).